# Serving HTML snippets on demand on same page

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do is, without changing the site location (for example from `example.com/snippet1` to `example.com/snippet`), using a select and only html and js (if possible). I want to avoid loading the entirety of the document (for example, avoid having 10 of those "snippets" with each being ~500 lines long loaded and instead choose which one I want to load while removing the rest).

Here's an example of the select/picker I have in mind, I could add a listener with js

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Snippet 1</option>
    <option value="2">Snippet 2</option>
</select>
```

Snippet 1:

```
<div class="s1">
    <p>something</p>
    <img src="s1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Snippet 2:

```
<div id="s2">
    <div class="s2">
        <iframe src=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's not about changing classes or ids, since the structure can be different between them. The intention is trying to make it work like an `include` with PHP.

Comment: These are typically called single page applications, and there's a lot of frameworks out there that help you with routing and loading additional content. Have you looked into Vue, Angular, or React? They all have a large number of tutorials to show you exactly how to do this.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying you have divs like `<div class="s1">` already on your page, and  you want to subseuqently populate those with the html retrieved from `example.com/snippet`, etc?

Comment: @mason I have thought about React, but I'm looking for a way to do it without it (which got me stuck!).

Comment: @DacreDenny Quite. The equivalent would be like including stuff in PHP. For example `include snippet1.php` or `include snippet2.php` (but not having both!) in `example.com/snippet`.

Comment: It's not hard. Break it down into small tasks. One task would be to load HTML from the server asynchronously. Research that. Try it out. Lots of tutorials for it. Another task would be to change the URL without reloading the page. Research that. Try it out. Lots of tutorials for it. You'll have to write some JavaScript to do it, and I don't see you making any attempt such as handling the select changed event.

Comment: @mason I didn't think about using ajax, good idea! My problem was how to start tackling the problem. My mind kept going to either php or react, and couldn't think of another option.

Comment: That's why you break it down into small issues and then tackle each separately. I think this is well within your grasp if you do.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this easily by using jQuery `load` and requesting the snippets from external html files.

This is super simple example where your snippet file names must correspond to the select option values, but you can add a map for more complex file name or locations.

Reference for jQuery load: http://api.jquery.com/load/

main js

```
$('select').on('change', function(event) {
  $('#content').load('snippet' + event.target.value + '.html');
});
```

index.html

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Snippet 1</option>
    <option value="2">Snippet 2</option>
</select>
<div id="content"></div>
```

snippet1.html

```
<div class="s1">
    <p>something</p>
    <img src="s1.jpg"/>
</div>
```

snippet2.html

```
<div id="s2">
    <div class="s2">
        <iframe src=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is pretty and exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It seems easy at first with plain JS or jQuery but it usually becomes a huge and slow mess because you'll add and change things. I learned it the hard way. It's also a lot better developer experience and it becomes a lot harder to write buggy code. I'd suggest to pick up a library, for example this is React.

https://reactjs.org/

I use static snippets here but you could just as well load them from server one by one (called code splitting).

---

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentSnippet: "1"
    };
  }
  
  changeSnippet(e) {
    this.setState({currentSnippet: e.target.value});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select 
          value={this.state.currentSnippet} 
          onChange={e => this.changeSnippet(e)}
        >
          <option value="1">Snippet 1</option>
          <option value="2">Snippet 2</option>
        </select>
        
        {this.state.currentSnippet === "1"
          ? <Snippet1 />
          : <Snippet2 />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

class Snippet1 extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>
        Hi, Im snippet 1
      </h1>
    );
  }
} 

class Snippet2 extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    return (
      <h2>
        Hi, Im snippet 2
      </h2>
    );
  }
} 

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't react be using Ajax in the background to fetch the html files?

Comment: Yes, `fetch, Ajax` or what every you want to call it and it would usually be JS files, not HTML. Ecosystem around these libraries is so rich that you could just write it as one simple app and tools split it automatically, so that user automatically only downloads what user sees, you don't have to write any networking code.

Comment: That's actually how everything with React works: you write what you want it look like and React does the rest. Look at my code, I don't have to get, update and delete DOM nodes. Not only is it better way to solve UI problems, it's also usually a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways this can be achieve - one simple approach based on vanilla javascript would be to iterate all `<div/>` elements in the document that snippets need to be fetched for, and then issue separate requests via `fetch()` to aquire and insert the HTML for those snippets. This appraoch would involve adding the snippet URL as a data attribute to the snippets present on the page rendered by your PHP script:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

  // For each element with data-url attribute
  document.body.querySelectorAll('[data-url]').forEach(snippetWrapper => {
  
    // Use fetch to get html snippet via url data attribute
    fetch(snippetWrapper.dataset.url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    // Assign the html to snippet wrappers innerHTML
    .then(html => { snippetWrapper.innerHTML = html; })  
  })  
})




/* Ignore this - just added so code snippet works */
async function fetch(url) {

    if(url === 'example.com/snippet1/') {
      return { 
        text : async () => 
        ` <img src="s1.jpg"/>` 
      }
    }
    
    if(url === 'example.com/snippet2/') {
      return { 
        text : async () => 
        `<div class="s2"><iframe src=""></iframe></div>` 
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="s2" data-url="example.com/snippet2/">
</div>
<div id="s1" data-url="example.com/snippet1/">
</div>
```